# Can Page Methods be used in .net 2.0 with Ajax extensions?

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-2.0, pagemethods

I need to call a server side method from JavaScript function in ASP.Net 2.0 framework. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
function focuslost() {

            mainForm.StartUpdating();
            var pagePath = window.location.pathname;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: pagePath + "/TextChanged",
                data: ("{ 'pNTID':'" + $("#<%= txtNTID.txtClientId%>").val()) + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    mainForm.EndUpdating()
                },
                success:
                                function(result) {


                                    if (result.d.length > 0) {

                                    }

                                    mainForm.EndUpdating()
                                }
            });

        }



 [WebMethod]
    public static string TextChanged(string pNTID)
    {
        retrun "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use WebMethod or AjaxMethod. Check Below

http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/Call-WebMethod-from-Javascript-in-ASPNET.aspx